# How to throw again IOException in java?

Tags: java, exception, methods, ioexception, throw

Code:

```
 catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException exception happened");
        //now need throw again the same exception to be 
                       //catched in    the    upper method
    }
```

But when I try simply:

```
  catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException exception happened");
        //now need throw again the same exception to be 
                       //catched in    the    upper method
               throw e;
    }
```

Eclipse supposes to me put  "throw e" in try catch block. But this is nonsense.
How fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: If you need IOException to propagate, just don't catch it.

Comment: what do you mean it's nonsense?

Comment: I need catch - because need first make specific in bottom method, and after common in upper method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129), that method needs to be declared as throwing `IOException` if you want it to propagate. For example:

```
void myMethod() throws IOException {
    try {
        //code
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException exception happened");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The second code fragment is just fine. Just remember that You have to declare Your method as:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `throws IOException` to your method, e.g.:

```
private void yourMethodName() throws IOException {
    # your method
}
```

Then Eclipse won't ask for the second try catch block.